# Impersonating Users in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, impersonation, training

We are about to start training our users.  We will do so via group webinars. There are several types of users (Attorneys, Secretaries, other admin, etc.) all of whom have different views.  Some have access to financial data, for example, while others don't.  The trainers don't have access to the data that attorneys will see.  If an trainer signs in as himself, then he cannot show a group of attorneys the view that they will see when they sign in.

How can the trainer get the view that the attorney has for use in the training sessions?  Impersonation?  Sign in as a fictitious user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2010, the Welcome Control (Top right, click on your name) has an option to "Sign in as Different User"

I recommend setting up fictitious user accounts in each role and using them.